# C++ project building using visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm working on an exe file  which needs projects made in visual studio 2010. But there is a project which works only when built in visual studio 2008(because of the external dependencies).

Now do we some mechanism so that i can compile the rest of the projects in visual studio 2010 and this special project in 2008

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

create the 2008 project as a dll and use it to work with your 2010 exe.

Answer (score 0):

in general, it is better do not mix code compiled with different compilers.  2008 and 2010 are using different run-times, so you will have problems. The easiest way it to create COM module with 2008 and use it.